# Визуализатор макета в Android Studio автоматически редактирует xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, design

Приветствую всех!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность отключить автоматическое редактирование xml макета визуализатором макетов в Android Studio ?

автоматически меняются настройки при переходе Design --> Text

Comment: Ничего не трогать в режиме Design :). Потому что это визуальный редактор, а не просто визуализатор и все изменения сразу прописываются в xml.

Comment: Да я вот и не трогаю его) Ситуация даже в том - когда я просто переключаюсь на него (не производя никаких действий с элементами UI) он всё равно прописывает значения для атрибутов :(

например ставит абсолютные значения для кнопок и лейблов и хардкодит ширину и высоту :)

наверное придётся "жаловаться" индусам в google

Comment: С ConstraintLayout такое бывает, если вы выставили какие-то некорректные или не все нужные констрейнты. Вот он и пытается таким образом исправить. Или у вас не констрейнт?

Comment: Понял! Спасибо! Действительно, поменял корневой ConstraintLayout на LinearLayoutCompat и Design "проказничать перестал" ...
Остаётся пересмотреть работу с ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

### **С ConstraintLayout такое бывает, если вы выставили какие-то некорректные или не все нужные констрейнты. Вот он и пытается таким образом исправить.**

***answer by [eugeneek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14141/eugeneek)***